# acts_as_taggable_on Tag_counts_on() method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I am currently having some trouble with the Model.tag_counts_on() method in the acts_as_taggable_on plugin in Rails. I can't find real documentation on the method and I want to know more about the parameters it accepts. I am trying to get tag counts on a **subset of tags**, not the whole set of tags on my application, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on`

This is the [master branch](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/collection.rb) of the gem in which the method appears in.

I would examine the conditions and on parameters.

```
def tag_counts_on(context, options = {})
  all_tag_counts(options.merge({:on => context.to_s}))
end

##
# Calculate the tag counts for all tags.
#
# @param [Hash] options Options:
# * :start_at   - Restrict the tags to those created after a certain time
# * :end_at     - Restrict the tags to those created before a certain time
# * :conditions - A piece of SQL conditions to add to the query
# * :limit      - The maximum number of tags to return
# * :order      - A piece of SQL to order by. Eg 'tags.count desc' or 'taggings.created_at desc'
# * :at_least   - Exclude tags with a frequency less than the given value
# * :at_most    - Exclude tags with a frequency greater than the given value
# * :on         - Scope the find to only include a certain context
def all_tag_counts(options = {})..end
```